# Color-coding a histogram

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a set of N objects with two properties: x and y.
I would like to depict the distribution of x with a histogram in MATPLOTLIB using hist(). Easy enough. Now, I would like to color-code EACH bar of the histogram with a color that represents the average value of y in that set with a colormap. Is there an easy way to do this? Here, x and y are both N-d numpy arrays. Thanks!

```
fig = plt.figure()
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, 100, normed=1, histtype='stepfilled')
plt.setp(patches, 'facecolor', 'g', 'alpha', 0.1)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('Normalized frequency')
plt.show()
```

Comment: You're capturing the `patches` object returned, can't you just iterate through that based on `bins` and set the colors as you see fit?

Comment: So I would have to manually check each of the N objects for which bin they are in, record the y there, and eventually take the average y to determine the color?

Comment: Something like that; first, I'd probably combine x and y into one array, then sort it by x.  After, iterate through the data, summing y then averaging and coloring when you see x cross a bin boundary.

Comment: This is actually a more interesting `numpy` problem than `matplotlib` problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# set up the bins
Nbins = 10
bins = np.linspace(0, 1, Nbins +1, endpoint=True)
# get some fake data
x = np.random.rand(300)
y = np.arange(300)
# figure out which bin each x goes into
bin_num = np.digitize(x, bins, right=True) - 1
# compute the counts per bin
hist_vals = np.bincount(bin_num)
# set up array for bins
means = np.zeros(Nbins)
# numpy slicing magic to sum the y values by bin
means[bin_num] += y
# take the average
means /= hist_vals

# make the figure/axes objects
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
# get a color map
my_cmap = cm.get_cmap('jet')
# get normalize function (takes data in range [vmin, vmax] -> [0, 1])
my_norm = Normalize()
# use bar plot 
ax.bar(bins[:-1], hist_vals, color=my_cmap(my_norm(means)), width=np.diff(bins))

# make sure the figure updates
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

related: [vary the color of each bar in bargraph using particular value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903750/vary-the-color-of-each-bar-in-bargraph-using-particular-value)

Comment: The "right" option of digitize is available on my Ubuntu machine, but not on my Mac... Hmmm.
with: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html
without: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21619347/creating-a-python-histogram-without-pylab/21632623#21632623 you can replicate the function of `digitize` with one pass through `x`