# How to manually add a legend with Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, seaborn

I would like to manually add `legends` to my `Seaborn plot`.

For example, the image below is the plot I am trying to manually add a legend to:

[image: r]

I would like to add a legend:

```
{
"1":"High efficiency",
"2": "High performance",
"3": "Effective performance",
"4": "Relatively low speed",
"5": "Reduce performance",
"6": "Not recommeneded"
}
```

Comment: Do you want to add a legend or change the X axis labels?  And, you add some sample data and code to generate your chart?

Comment: Add legends to the plot

Comment: does this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32261619/how-to-add-legend-on-seaborn-facetgrid-bar-plot?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56396248/6660373

Answer (score 1):

**Try:**

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

x=[1,1000,1001]
y=[200,300,400]
sns.set_context(rc={"figure.figsize": (8, 4)})
nd = np.arange(3)
width=0.8
plt.xticks(nd+width/2., ('1','1000','1001'))
plt.xlim(-0.15,3)

ax = sns.barplot(x=x,y=y)
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b']

labels = {
    1:'x',
    1000:'y',
    1001:'z'
}
handles = []
for col, lab, patch in zip(colors, x, ax.axes.patches):
    patch.set_color(col)
    handles.append(mpatches.Patch(color=col, label=labels[lab]))

ax.legend(handles=handles) 
plt.show()
```

[image]