# Fill in horizontal barplot rectangles based on value in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to color the rectangles of a horizontal bar plot based on their value as reflected in a colormap I have. Is there a way to iterate over each rectangle and make the color reflect its value on the colormap?

Here is what I'm working with if you're interested

I have my x and y values and put them into a normal horizontal barplot like so, and I have some labels at the end denoting values like so:

```
plt.barh(x, y)

for i, v in enumerate(y):
    ax.text(v + 1, i - .15 , str(v))
```

The horizontal bar graph looks like this:
[image]

Here is the colormap I want to use:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(0.5, 16))
colorBar = plt
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.5)

cmap = mpl.cm.YlGn
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=1, vmax=100)

cb1 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax, cmap=cmap,
                                norm=norm,
                                orientation='vertical')
fig.show()
```

Sorry it's gigantic.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out, based on the answer in this post:

[vary the color of each bar in bargraph using particular value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903750/vary-the-color-of-each-bar-in-bargraph-using-particular-value)

```
cmap = mpl.cm.YlGn
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=1, vmax=100)
ax = fig.add_axes([.1,.1,1,1])
plt.barh(x, y, color=cmap(norm(y)))

for i, v in enumerate(y):
    ax.text(v + 1, i - .15 , str(v))
```

[image]