# Method to generate 'N' random colors 'P' times using get_cmap().colors. Error: 'LinearSegmentedColormap' object has no attribute 'colors'. Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to generate N random colors P times. For example I have 10 different plots with 20 bars in each and I wan to assign each bar a different color. How can I generate 20 random colors for each bar for 10 times?

I have written this code but it is showing me errors.

```
def generate_n_random_cmap(how_many=20,list_len=10):
    '''
    Generate list of 20 colors 10 times by default. 
    NOTE: Colors can be duplicated if lit_len is greater than length of plt.colormap()
    '''
    import random
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    c_list = []
    while len(c_list)!=list_len:
        try:
            c_list.append(plt.cm.get_cmap(random.choice(plt.colormaps()),how_many).colors)
        except :
            None
    return random.shuffle(c_list)
```

And the Error I get is:

```
'LinearSegmentedColormap' object has no attribute 'colors'
```

Is there any other method? Colors should be random in nature.

Answer (score 2):

There are few things. As the error message says, the object you get has no attribute color. As the [manual](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.html) says, `Make a linear segmented colormap with name from a sequence of colors which evenly transitions from colors[0] at val=0 to colors[-1] at val=1.`

Second, what you do is you're getting a list of paletts. One way of doing what you want is for each graph to randomly select `how_many` colours you want and then plot your bars accordingly, eg.:

```py
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

how_many = 20 
# Create a list of colours randomly selected from the list of matplotlib colours
c_list = [np.random.choice(list(mcolors.CSS4_COLORS.values())) for i in range(how_many)] 
barlist=plt.bar(np.arange(len(c_list)), np.arange(len(c_list))) 
for i in range(len(c_list)):
    barlist[i].set_color(c_list[i])
```

[image: Method one]

The other thing you could do is to generate different palettes, eg. using seaborn or even matplotlib, you can use your random selection of a palette `np.random.choice(plt.colormaps())`. Relevant information can be found in [manual of seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.color_palette.html) or those posts:
[How to give a pandas/matplotlib bar graph custom colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927715/how-to-give-a-pandas-matplotlib-bar-graph-custom-colors), https://stackoverflow.com/a/18991446/12281892.

Comment: I've found out that there are only certain Colormaps which can produce more than 20  to a million different colors using try catch in a loop. For random, I could have easily used ```random.random()``` in a tuple of 3 followed by a single 1 for ```RGBA``` but that is not what I wanted. Anyways thanks for your help so that I could find the answer.