# How can xtick labels refer to labels instead of index numbers?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a [Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4dtc.png) which I'm using to create a bar plot.

[image]

This is the code that generated the plot.

```py
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    import pandas as pd
    gendercrcard=pd.DataFrame({'Gender':['Female','Female','Male','Male'],'Hascrcard':['No','Yes','No','Yes'],'count':[1351,3192,1594,3863]})
    gendercrcard.plot(kind='bar')
    plt.title('Credit Card Status with Gender', size = 20)
    plt.xticks(size = 15, rotation = 0)
    plt.ylabel('Frequency', size = 15)
    plt.show()
```

My `xticks` currently correspond to their index in the `df`. However, the index number do not provide context.

Is there a way to change them so that they say 'Male/Female' and 'Credit card/No credit card'?

I'd Also like to change the colour of the boxes (e.g. male = blue and female = pink).

Comment: Please add your current code that you want to improve.

Comment: Edit made @Erich

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The x-axis by default is the index of your dataframe. If no specific index us set, the numbers 0,1,2,... are the default index.

Comment: @yupper can you show how u expecting output. if u can add an expected  graphical output it would be great

Answer (score 1):

Since no code has been given to work with, here are the general solutions to your problem.

To manipulate/customize your xticks please refer to the [Documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html)

To change the color of your Barplots, the solution to that has already been answered in the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903750/vary-the-color-of-each-bar-in-bargraph-using-particular-value).

Or consider reading the [Documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html).