# different colors of the bars from directly plotting dataset

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I it possible to have different colors on my barplot straight from pandas plot without specifying them. Here is what I am referring about:
I have this dataframe:

```
 df
 Personnage    Puissance
 J. Wick        82
 J. Bond        72
 J. Bourne      85
 J. Rambo       91
 J. McLane      83
```

When I use `df.plot(kind='bar')` all my bars are blue.I would like to use  an argument to get the different colors without manually specifying them.

Comment: Do you need only bar? Scatter is allowed?

Comment: @toRex yes, only bars.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vary the color of each bar in bargraph using particular value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903750/vary-the-color-of-each-bar-in-bargraph-using-particular-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you open to `seaborn`:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.barplot(x='Personnage', y='Puissance', data=df)
```

Output:

[image]

With matplotlib, you can just loop the data:

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    plt.bar(row['Personnage'], row['Puissance'])
```

and you get pretty much the same output with different alpha:

[image]